# Can one use Eisenstein criteria in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Since I can not find this in a book, I want to ask the question here. Given a polynomial in a polynomial ring in one variable over $\mathbb{F}_p,$ can one use the Eisenstein criteria to decide if the polynomial is irreducible. For example we may take $x^7 + 6x^3 + 12x − 3$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but how about if we consider this in $\mathbb{F}_5 [x]$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you test this yourself first with a computer algebra package, even Wolfram Alpha? Modulo $5$, it factors as $(x^3+2x^2+3)(x^4+3x^3+4x^2+4x+4)$. Your example $x^7 + 6x^3 + 12x - 3$ is a striking one for your idea, since it's reducible in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ for *every* prime $p < 100$. The first $p$ for which it is irreducible mod $p$ is $p = 103$. Reread a proof of the Eisenstein criterion in $\mathbf Z[x]$ to appreciate why it is not reasonable to expect something like it should work directly in $\mathbf F_p[x]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{F_p}$ is a field, and so it doesn't have any irreducible elements. So Eisenstein criterion doesn't make sense here. And no, irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't imply irreducibility over $\mathbb{F_p}$ after reducing the coefficients mod $p$. For example, $x^2+1$ splits in $\mathbb{F_2}[x]$.

Eisenstein criterion is useful when you want to check irreducibility of a polynomial in $R[x]$ over the field of fractions of $R$, where $R$ is some UFD domain. The classical cases are $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $R=F[x]$ where $F$ is some field. So if you want to check irreducibility of a polynomial in **two variables** over $\mathbb{F_p}$, then you can indeed use the criterion. For example:

$t^p-x\in\mathbb{F_p}[x][t]$

is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ by Eisenstein criterion, because $x$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{F_p}[x]$.